# How to style svg in svelte custom element

Tags: svelte

In "normal" svelte you can use the global modifier, but how to do if you use a web component?

```js
<script lang="ts">
  import MyLogo from "./assets/icons/logo.svg"
</script>

<MyLogo class="my-logo" viewBox="0 0 114 49"/>

<style lang="scss">
:global(.my-logo) {
  ...
}
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use CSS custom properties:

```html
<script>
  import MyLogo from "./assets/icons/logo.svg"
</script>

<div style="display: contents; --logo-color: blue">
  <MyLogo class="my-logo" viewBox="0 0 114 49"/>
</div>
```

```html
<!-- logo.svg -->
<svg>
  <text style="fill: var(--logo-color)">my logo</text>
</svg>
```